# Ruby on Rails: GeoKit Zipcode Search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zipcode

I am having problems getting a zip code search to work with GeoKit. Some error is making the whole app crash.

This is what I have:

```
 def zipcode
    zipcode = params[:zipcode]
    @bathrooms = Bathroom.geo_scope(:all, :origin=>[zipcode], :within=>10)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json  { render :json => @bathrooms }
      #format.json { render :json => {:bathrooms => @bathrooms} }
      format.js   { render :nothing => true } 
     end        
  end




 match '/bathrooms/zipcode', :controller => 'bathrooms', action =>"zipcode"
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
 ArgumentError in BathroomsController#zipcode

wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Rails.root: /Users/chance 1/source/rails_projects/squat
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/bathrooms_controller.rb:44:in `geo_scope'
app/controllers/bathrooms_controller.rb:44:in `zipcode'

Request

Parameters:

{"zipcode"=>"47130",
 "format"=>"json"}

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the actual error? You can find the error/stacktrace in the Rails logs (logs/development.log)

Comment: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/bathrooms/zipcode.json"):

Comment: Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (2.5ms)

Comment: I found one of the errors in the routing table. But now I have, "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)"

Comment: Now, unknown key origin....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geo_scope` expects [only one argument](https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3/blob/master/lib/geokit-rails3/acts_as_mappable.rb#L108): a hash. You are passing it two arguments: a symbol (`:all`) and a hash (`:origin=>[zipcode], :within=>10`). It is receiving two arguments when it expects only one, giving you the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

There are two ways to solve this.

First, you can remove the `:all` symbol and use a finder method:

```
Bathroom.geo_scope(:origin=>[zipcode], :within=>10).all
```

Or, you could forget GeoKit altogether and use [geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com) instead. [(github)](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)

```
# GeoKit
@bathrooms = Bathroom.geo_scope(:origin=>[zipcode], :within=>10).all

# geocoder
@bathrooms = Bathroom.near(zipcode, 10)
```

Comment: I tried the GeoKit suggestion and now am getting this error:
47130 (Array) cannot be normalized to a LatLng. We tried interpreting it as an array, string, Mappable, etc., but no dice. Mmmm????

Comment: But this worked...
@bathrooms = Bathroom.geo_scope(:origin=>params[:zipcode], :within=>10).all